# Window focus adds characters to shell

Tags: shell, tmux, fish

This is a very strange bug that I can't seem to track down.  I'm using the fish shell and after I launch and disconnect from a TMUX session, every time the window loses focus a "[O" is added to the prompt and every time the window gains focus a "[I" is added to the console.  This means that if I cmd+tab to another window (or just click out of the window and back in) the prompt would look like:
`$ [O[I`

EDIT:  Pertinent information.  This only seems to happen in the fish shell, not bash.  It only happens after attaching to a tmux session (or making a new one) and the disconnecting.  Opening a new window I do not have the issue.

Minor annoyance, but I just want to know what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was because of the `tmux set-option -g focus-events on` setting being set by tmux-sensible plugin.  This allows for you to pass on focus events to vim inside of tmux (which I don't do) the issue it seems is that it wasn't being turned off when tmux exited. I simply commented it out, as I don't use features that depend on it.

Comment: Hey, tmux-sensible maintainer here. Would you please consider opening a pull request that detects if a users users 'fish' shell so that `focus-events` option can be turned off? That way we fix the problem for all fish shell users? I even opened an [issue](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-sensible/issues/20). Thanks